# Blender. Holes after Parent with Automatic Weights

Tags: blender, mesh, modeling, skeleton

please help me with a small issue. I'm beginner in blender, and I got this problem after I parent mesh to skeleton with Automatic Weights. The verticles are merged in Edit mode.
The problem appears after I selected a part of mesh like (Jacket) and add additional material. I did that with all objects on character. Now when I'm in pose mode I got this issue.
[Heres the vide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H4liwbHJJCE)

Please can someone help me with that ?

Thank you.

I try to do something in weight paint but it was unuseful.